# Send <input name="array[key]"> with curl?

Tags: php, curl, web-crawler

I have a crawler that I want to be able to submit a form on the target site.

**The HTML of the form is:**

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.hemnet.se/sok/create">
    <input name="search[keywords]" type="hidden" value="Uppsala">
    <button class="button primary" type="submit"><span>Search</span></button>
</form>
```

So I found out that the target site needs `search[keywords]` to be set. It could be "" or a string, anything goes. But it needs to be set to display the search result.

**My curl for this is:**

```
$url = 'http://www.hemnet.se/sok/create';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'search[keywords]=Uppsala' );
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I have tried many different combinations of the `POSTFIELDS`. For example:

```
$fields = array('search' => array('keywords' => 'Uppsala'));
$fieldset = http_build_query($fields);
```

With or without the `http_build_query()`. Everything fails. I have also tried changing the Content-Type of the call without any success. All attempts result in the target website not recognizing the postfields to be set and then redirecting me to its root/landing page.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Give us the form page - can't find it....

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('search[keywords]' => 'Uppsala');
```

Comment: Not working for me. Is it really working for you or just taking a guess?

Comment: @MarcusLind Not a guess, it's working on my environment.

Comment: So you get a search result page with a list of real estate objects in the area? (Like this: http://i.imgur.com/2FIzfeG.png)

For me, I get redirected to the root page (www.hemnet.se). 

Can you upload/share your complete curl code?

Comment: @MarcusLind No, I didn't test on that site, btw, the site may have some mechanisms to block crawlers.

Comment: But if I can submit a HTML form against the website from my localhost, I should be able to submit a curl POST from my localhost too, right? There can't be any javascript or such to disable crawlers if I'm able to submit that simple HTML form that I posted in my question.

Comment: @MarcusLind I get the search result.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the job:

```
$fields = array('search[keywords]' => 'Uppsala');
$fieldset = http_build_query($fields);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are not doing `multipart` form posting, and which is wrong. So just remove this and it will work for you:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data'));
```